# Copy/pasting something that's clickable

Tags: hyperlinks, highlight, copy-paste

I have a use case where an element on the page is the most obvious place to link from the list view to the instance view, but users also sometimes need to copy/paste the element text.

Because the element is a link, people have to be careful where they click when they highlight the element to copy it.

Are there any ideas for how to support both clicking and copy/pasting the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an [Edit] button which would be visible inside the cell. A click on the edit button would display the content in plain text format (assuming that the entire cell is a link) in a Text area or a TextBox. This would enable the user to mark content, copy and paste without having to worry about the link.

When being in edit mode, I would provide three new buttons below the editable area to enable the user to [Copy] the text and/or [Save] or [Cancel] the edit.

**Edit:**
*I have provided an optional answer in the mockup, if the user shouldn't be able to edit the link text (thanks to Vitalys comment).*

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOrtnH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

A right click could work for computers, but it would not work on touch interfaces, so lets leave the right click out of the equation.

Comment: Why would you provide an Edit button if the item isn't editable? :) (as far as we know)

Comment: I just assumed that the copy/paste action were supposed to work on the link text as well. We'll just have to wait and see what happens when they wake up :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple: you just provide a "copy" button next to the item. The way URL shortening services do:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this copy button copy the link and not the "element text"? :)

Comment: The link *is* the element text in this case.

Comment: Oh, that's true! It got me confused, since text and link are equal.